# How do I make the overlay appear above image in Elementor?For more details see snapshot

Tags: wordpress, overlay, elementor

[image]I am using Elementor page builder with Astra Theme.
I want the overlay above the image but for some reason it is coming behind the image.

Please see the snapshot.

Comment: You just set the overlay for **the column - not the image**. And you put the i mage inside the column - that mean the image **above**  the column of course!

Comment: Please to hear that. If my solution work for you, please mark it working. So first, i can have some points and second, others have same problem can easy to find the  working solution!

Comment: I have create a better version [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4sCOUPvEw60) - allow you to auto dimamic add overlays to any image without coding.

Answer (score -1):

i have think about your question. And we can use this trick to gain that:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    let image = jQuery("#tho-overlay");
        let cdiv = image.closest(".elementor-column");
        cdiv.append('<div class= "tho-div" style="width:'+cdiv.width()+'px; height:'+cdiv.height()+'px; background-color:red; position:absolute; opacity:.2;"></div>');
});
</script>
```

All you need is set the id for your image. Then add a new HTML block, paste above code, change coresspon info (your image's id, background color and opacity) that you want.

## UPDATE:

I have create a better version [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4sCOUPvEw60&t=24s) - allow you to auto dynamic add overlays to any image without coding

Comment: Can't this be resolved using elementor page builder?Using z-index or something.I am not sure if jquery is present by default in wordpress.

Comment: You can looking for others solutions. But z-index not working - i had tried it. And of course Wordpress have default built-in jquery!